# Amazon Alexa/Feit Electric/Google Assistant/Apple's Siri website interface or portal?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, google-assistant-sdk, sirishortcuts

I'm plenty proficient with Python's `Selenium` module which is for web interaction/automation. I have a Feit Electric Smart Wifi Plug that I'm looking to work with. Feit seems to have one mobile (barely decent) app but no desktop accessible website to control their products.

They do seem to work with Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant. I paired it up via the mobile Alexa app (you don't actually need to have an Alexa to pair the plug to the Alexa app). I learned Alexa has a web interface (alexa.amazon.com) but upon further investigation, it only shows the name of the device (Feit smartplug) and the option to remove it, it does not let me interact with it.

Google Assistant doesn't even have a website (as far as I can tell) otherwise I'd try that. Essentially what I'm looking for is a website to control this product with, it should be one of the following.

- A better Amazon Alexa profile that lets me interact with the devices (unless someone can show me how to do that with the current one)
- An online Google Assistant interface where I can control my device
- Some type of Feit Electric online website to control my devices

I should add it works with Siri shortcuts, so if I can access Siri Shortcuts online, that would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, it seems like you're looking for a web-based way to control this device and not necessarily integrate with one of the assistant platforms.

The assistant platforms mentioned are generally meant to be processed on a mobile device or speaker and don't necessarily have a web-based runner. Though there are some APIs meant for embedded devices, I don't think you'd want that.

Instead, I think what you'd probably want instead is to look at using a platform like [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/), which provides a mechanism for controlling various smart home devices through various interfaces including web. There's one example of someone [connecting the Feit bulbs to Home Assistant on top of the Tuya platform](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/feit-smart-bulb/75445). That post includes how they set it up, and a handful of caveats they ran into.